# Mixing secured users and visitors on the same site

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, devise

I suspect this is more a question of best practices than code.  If I have a site (RoR3 and Devise) where a registered user can upload and create documents into a database with the normal collection of views.  Of course the user must first sign up and log into the site.  Having created a document they might want to send out a link to another person who is not registered with the site (and won't be).

So what I envision is a set of views that are "read only" if you will where the invited person can view the document but can't navigate outside that view, except for the home page.  Devise doesn't seem to have the concept of a non logged in visitor that I can see and I haven't found anyone who has done this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this can get tricky, especially if non-registered users can do some stuff but not all.  We tried a couple of approaches to solve this problem in a company I recently worked for, including the invitations aspect you mentioned.

Because our entire app revolved around users, when a user visited the site, we created an instance of User.  If the user was signed in the user model would be backed by a database record, and if not, they were just a virtual user and we used session data to store semi-persistent state information.

In application_controller we set `current_user` to either the real user or just an object, so it was always available, and quacked like a user, especially including a `registered?` method

At first we wrapped tons of stuff in our views with `if current_user.registered?` all over the place.  But that quickly got to be a mess.  The better pattern (in cases where the differences were significant) would be to create partials that like `_sidebar` and `_sidebar_registered`, so we could create a method that, given the root name of a partial rendered the appropriate one depending on user state.

In the case of invitations where users have limited access to content if they were invited, we wrote an invitation module that was backed by a model.  The invitER could send an email from the system, or generate a URL with an embedded token.  We stored the token in a table so we knew who invited whom, which was necessary in our case -- looking up the token was all that was needed to authenticate. Once the user was sorta-authenticated, we stored the state in the session, and a method on User (`invited?`) would let us know if the user had access.

In general there were certain whole controller actions that only registered users could get at (e.g. edit/delete) we would just use before_filters in the controller to control access.  It's mostly in the view's that things got messy.

We did look at CanCan as we started getting different levels of user authorization.  But I can tell you, this can balloon into rather gnarly code quickly unless you carefully segregate who can see and do what.

Comment: Good approach.  Did you ever play with using a sub-domain or names scopes?

Comment: Subdomains will mess with SEO -- in our case, the page an unregistered visitor would see had substantially the same content as a registered user, so needed to be the same URL.  Named scopes ... not so much: in the end, there was a simple decision made and stored before the first page any user came to was seen; in our case, it was just a matter of how much information and what kind a registered user saw vs. not.

Comment: Good point I had not thought about the SEO.  Seams like simple works again :)  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Devise provides you with the user_signed_in? method and the current_user method to help you with this kind of thing. For example, in your view you could have something along the lines of:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
   <%= current_user.username %>
<% end %>
```

etc.

If your permissions get more complicated, I would recommend using an authorization gem to help you manage your restricted sections. A couple of examples are [Declarative Authorzation](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) (my personal favorite) and [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).